# Непонятки с работой COM-порта в асинхронном режиме

Tags: c#, com-порт

Задача написать приложение, работающее с пулом COM-портов, к которым подключены модемы. Вначале выбирается свободный модем:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstPorts.Count; i++)
{ 
    if (lstPorts[i].Status == "Ожидает")
    {
        PortNum = lstPorts[i].Title;
        lstPorts[i].Status = "В работе";
        break;
    }
}
```

Затем, в этой же процедуре вызывается процедура опроса модема

```
await Task.Run(() => ModemPolling(PortNum));
```

Данная процедура вначале выбирает номер модема, потом вызывает процедуру работы с COM портом и модемом (расположена в другом классе)

```
async void ModemPolling(string PortN)
{
    int Jp = lstModem.Items.Count;
    phModel phMod;
    string telN=string.Empty;
    string SNum=string.Empty;
    clsProcess proc;

    proc = new clsProcess();
    proc.onStr += onProcStr;
    proc.onEnd += onEndProc;

    for (int j = 0; j < Jp; j++)
    {
        phMod = (phModel)lstModem.Items[j];
        if (phMod.Status == 0)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => ((phModel)lstModem.Items[j]).Status = 1));
            telN = ((phModel)lstModem.Items[j]).PnoneN;
            SNum = ((phModel)lstModem.Items[j]).SerialN;
            break;
        }
    }

    await Task.Run(() => proc.ModemProc(PortN, telN, SNum));
}
```

Вспомогательный класс номера модема

```
public class phModel 
{
        string _serialN;
        string _pnoneN;
        int _hResult;
        int _status;
        int _pError;

    //серийный номер
    public string SerialN
    {
        get => _serialN;
        set=>_serialN = value;
    }

    //телефонный номер
    public string PnoneN
    {
        get => _pnoneN;
        set=>_pnoneN = value;
    }

    //результат выполнения операции
    public int HResult
    {
        get => _hResult;
        set=>_hResult = value;
    }

    //статус модема (свободен, занят, завершил работу, ошибка)
    public int Status
    {
        get => _status;
        set=>_status = value;
    }

    //код ошибки
    public int PError
    {
        get => _pError;
        set=>_pError = value;
    }

    public void SetStatus(int inSt)
    {
        _status = inSt;
    }
}
```

И собственно, сама процедура работы с модемом

```
public void ModemProc(string portNum, string telNum, string serialN)
{
    portNumber = portNum;
    TelNum = telNum;
    SNumber = serialN;

    try
    {
        _port = new SerialPort(portNum)
        {
            BaudRate = _speed,
            Parity = _stParity,
            WriteTimeout = _tsT,
            ReadTimeout = _rsT,
            StopBits = _stBits,
            DataBits = _dBits,
            Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff,
            DtrEnable = true,
            RtsEnable = true,
            NewLine = Environment.NewLine,
            DiscardNull = true
        };
        if (!_port.IsOpen)
            _port.Open();
        _port.DataReceived += _port_DataReceived;
        var na = new NotifyArgs(1, 1, "Порт " + portNum + " открыт.", 0, portNumber, TelNum);
        onStr?.Invoke(na);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        int pRes = ModemConnect(telNum);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}

public void PortClose(string pNum)
{
    if (_port.IsOpen)
        _port.Close();
    var na = new NotifyArgs(1, 2, "Порт " + pNum + " закрыт.", 0, portNumber, TelNum);
    onStr?.Invoke(na);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}

int ModemConnect(string modemNum)
{
    _port.Write("+++\r\n");
    _port.Write("ATE1\r\n");
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    _port.Write("ATH0\r\n"); // установка режима ожидания 
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    _port.Write("AT+IFC=0,2\r\n"); // устанавливается режим контроля над передачей
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    _port.Write("at+cbst=7,0,1\r\n"); // устанавливается прозрачный режим 
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(modemNum, @"(8|\+)9[0-9]{9}"))
        return 11;
    _port.Write("ATDT " + modemNum + "\r\n" + " ");
         return 0;
}

void modemDisconnect()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        _port.Write("+++\r\n");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        _port.WriteLine("ATH0\r\n"); // установка режима ожидания
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    catch 
    {
    }
}
```

NotifyArgs - вспомогательный класс, который передает информацию в главную форму приложения.

Вызовы методов modemDisconnect() и PortClose() расположены в конце методов, производящих обработку данных полученных от модема.

В синхронном режиме (для одного COM - порта) все работает отлично. Но мне нужно задействовать все свободные модемы пула (которые имеют статус "Ожидает"). Собственно, программа и написана для асинхронного режима.

Однако, на практике очень часто (но не каждый раз) приложение рушится с ошибкой

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Дескриптор SafeHandle был закрыт'
```

Лог ошибки

```
   System.ObjectDisposedException
   HResult=0x80131622
   Message=Дескриптор SafeHandle был закрыт
   Source=mscorlib
   StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
   at Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetOverlappedResult(SafeFileHandle 
   hFile, NativeOverlapped* lpOverlapped, Int32& lpNumberOfBytesTransferred, 
   Boolean bWait)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.EventLoopRunner.WaitForCommEvent()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Ошибка возникает после попытки исполнить строку кода

```
_port.Write("ATDT " + modemNum + "\r\n" + " ");
```

Бьюсь над проблемой уже четвертые сутки. В интернете адекватной информации о SafeHandle и как с ним бороться так и не нашел.. Может кто-то подскажет, что делать..

Comment: Похоже на то, что  идёт попытка записи в закрытый порт. Дело именно в "ATDT " ? Предыдущие команды write проходят  (если набор номера убрать)?

Comment: Да именно. Ошибка возникает именно на этой строке. Убирать ее я пробовал - ошибка сразу же пропала. Причем ошибка проявляется не сразу, а по истечению некоторого (и довольно длительного) времени. Набор номера и установление связи - довольно длительная операция. Я проверял, команда записи набора номера на модем уходит..

Comment: Выглядит так, как будто вы одновременно вызвали ModemPolling для одного и того же порта в разных потоках.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема действительно оказалась в том, что набор номера и установление связи с модемом - очень длительная операция. Сборщик мусора не дожидается следующей реакции модема (это процедура _port_DataReceived) и уничтожает порт.

для решения проблемы оказалось достаточно добавить две строки.

```
        _port.Write("ATDT " + modemNum + "\r\n" + " ");
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        _port.Write("\r\n");
```

Я, конечно же, понимаю, что данное решение является "костылем". Дальше буду работать попытавшись переопределить IDisposable.

Comment: А не лучше ли вынести локальную переменную порта (или список активных портов) уровнем выше, чтобы GC не спешил?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(10000);` выглядит печально, конечно. Особенно если этим приложением будет кто-то пользоваться (10 секунд ждать отклика без уведомления об этом пользователя).

Comment: Получается никто никого не ждет. Программа отправляет модему команду ATDT, и на этом ее миссия завершена.  Дальше набор номера и установление связи производит аппаратно сам модем. И в момент прихода ответа СONNECT (А ответ приходит в отдельном потоке)  оказывается, что порт уже удален. Посылая на модем пустую строку, я "напоминаю" сборщику мусора, что порт еще нужен. Решение проблемы я вижу в переопределении IDisposible. Может подскажите, как это сделать. У меня пока ума не хватает..